# How can I fetch the URL and title of a web page in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am currently working with a social media share button and I was wondering if there is any way to render the page title and URL automatically with PHP instead of writing  it manually each time (the basic idea is that I will use the same code in different  pages).

Example:

```
http://twitter.com/home?status= **[TITLE]** + **[URL]**

**PAGE ONE:**
Page Title: Testpage - TestFTW1
Page URL: example.com/test1
```

I want "TestFTW1" to appear in the [TITLE] and "example.com/test1" in [URL].

```
**PAGE TWO:**
Page Title: Testpage - TestFTW2
Page URL: example.com/test2
```

I want `"TestFTW2"` to appear in the [TITLE] and "example.com/test2" in [URL].

Comment: Hang on. Are you trying to request the title of the *current* page? Don't you know the title, as you're building the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You can get the URL of the current page like this

`$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`

It uses `$_SERVER` which is an array with mainly headers of the page. HTTP_HOST will return the host, like "example.com".
REQUEST_URI will return the current URI, like "/index.php".

#### And the title like this

```
$str = file_get_contents($url);
if (strlen($str) > 0) {
    preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
    $pageName = $title[1];
}
```

The function `file_get_contents()` will return all the content of the specified web page as a string. The function `preg_match()` will search for the title with the regular expression.

Or like this

```
$pageName = substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond, but could you be more specific how its done.

Comment: For exampel, <php include .... > etc.

Comment: I tried to explain more some functions and variables. You can find more informations on Google by typing the name of the function or the variable. You can also type keywords like "get title php", "get current url php". You'll find what you need.